# Convert 2D Vector to FFTW_Complex

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, fftw

In My program I have 2D `Vector` like (`vector<vector<double>> Data(ROWS, vector<double>(COLS));`),then I implement `FFTW` to take `FFT` from my vector with :

```
fftw_complex in[ROWS][COLS], out[ROWS][COLS];
fftw_plan g;


g = fftw_plan_dft_2d(ROWS, COLS, *in, *out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
```

How can I convert my `vector` to `fftw_complex in[ROWS][COLS]` for input `fftw_plan_dft_2d` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements of `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` are not contiguous in memory, whereas elements of `S[rows][cols]` are contiguous. To convert between them you have to copy (and transform, if types `T` and `S` are distinct) elements row by row. The general solution:

```
template<typename T, typename S, class Op, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols>
void transform_vec_vec_to_mat(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& from, Op op, S (&to)[rows][cols]) {
    assert(from.size() == rows);
    for (std::size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        assert(from[row].size() == cols);
        std::transform(from[row].begin(), from[row].end(), to[row], op);
    }
}

std::vector<std::vector<double>> data;
std::complex<double> in[rows][cols];

const auto double_to_complex = [](double d) { return std::complex<double>{d, 0}; };
transform_vec_vec_to_mat(data, double_to_complex, in);
```

Keep in mind, that real input can be treated as a special case to save computational time and space. See [the official documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html) for more details.